# Stop Masonry re-sizing when not all images are loaded

Tags: wordpress, masonry

I am using Masonry (and imagesLoaded) with Wordpress:

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/masonry/3.3.2/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
```

and my site includes a number of images that ranges between 1 to 8 MB. I have noticed that the loading times are very long (I am using no pagination on Wordpress, so the page loads all content) and the grid keeps resizing until all images are loaded.

Is there a way to fix this?

This is my custom js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    let $masonryGrid = $('.masonry-grid');
    $masonryGrid.imagesLoaded(() => {
        $masonryGrid.masonry({
            columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
            itemSelector: '.grid-item',
            gutter: 0,
            percentPosition: true,
            transitionDuration: 0
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: compress your images https://tinypng.com/

Comment: Thank you, Is there anything else I can do as part of Masonry itself?

Comment: Did you add the `imagesLoaded` library? http://imagesloaded.desandro.com/
It is not included in Masonry, you have to include it separately.

Comment: Yes, it is included

Comment: Images that are above 500KB in size can be very problematic, 8MB is just way too much for a web image. Your site will stall on load, and users will leave if it loads longer than 5-10sec...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a preview version for all of your images - same dimensions, but drastically downscaled quality. Maybe with a "Loading" text or symbol over them.

Those previews should have the same filename with a suffix. You will have pairs of images like this

```
image001.jpg
image001_thumb.jpg
```

Then the individual image elements will then automatically start loading the full version :

```
<img src="image001_thumb.jpg" onload="this.src=this.src.replace('_thumb','');" />
```

And if you cannot directly influence image elements like this, add this to your custom .ready function (this is an example that would affect *all* images, just to give you an idea, you have to filter out only the images that are inside the grid)

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for(var i=0;i<images.length;i++){
 // If the image is already loaded, change it immediately
 if(images[i].naturalWidth != 0) images[i].src = images[i].src.replace('_thumb','');
 else // If not, give it an onLoad function to change after it does
 images[i].onload = function(){
  this.src = this.src.replace('_thumb','');
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For a better experience, maybe you can try to reveal each item after its image has loaded.

**See the [extra exemples section](http://masonry.desandro.com/extras.html#extra-examples) on Masonry docs**

> Iteratively reveal items after each image is loaded. See explanation on [issue #501](https://github.com/desandro/masonry/issues/501#issuecomment-34581431)